# What should happen after bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start?

Tags: installation, apache-zeppelin

I have been trying to install Zeppelin on my Mac.  I got to the stage of bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start and the terminal tells me it is successful.  The log also says the server is connected.  However nothing happens.  When I visit localhost:8080, it says the site cannot be found.
What should have happened after I run the command bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start?
Thank you.
Wing